# How to convert Date on MySQL (variable error)

Tags: mysql, date

I have created this table on MySQL :

```
create table Apolo(
Date date,
Name varchar(50)
);
```

I have imported an excel file :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/File.csv'
INTO TABLE Apolo
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 10 ROWS
(@Date, Name);
set Date=str_to_date(@Date,'%d/%m/%Y');
```

and I get the error :

**Error Code: 1193. Unknown system variable 'Date'**

If I do not put this line :

```
set Date=str_to_date(@Date,'%d/%m/%Y');
```

I do not get the error but if I try to use :

```
select count(*) from Apolo where Date='03/09/2015';
```

it does not work. So the format is not recognisable.

Comment: is your data imported successfully along with date? also i see you create a table name `Apolo` but when you run query `select count(*) from Apolo_BBC`  here table name is change `Apolo_BBC`

Comment: @Noman I changed the table name for stackoverflow. In MySQL it is correct. The problem is not this one :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Date column values in database. By default date format in mysql database is **Y-m-d**

Do you have values in this format.

Comment: The date on the .csv file is shown as "03/09/2015".

Comment: You are right on this. But you need to change this to Y-m-d format before insert to database. If you dont want to change format before insert, make sure your date column in database table contain dates.

Answer (score 1):

The **date** to insert into **mysql** database should be in the format

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

Example: `2015-02-18`

So change the `date` in csv file to the above specified format and try ..

Answer (score 0):

Take the semi-colon out of this line

```
(@Date, Name);
```

The `set` should be in the same command. Watch out for the fact that you have a field name that is a reserved word - you may need to escape it.

Comment: I did that. The date on the .csv file is shown as "03/09/2015". I deleted the semicolon and then proceeded with this query :
select count(*) from Apolo where Date='03/09/2015'; but I get 0 as a result.

Comment: I don't know what your csv looks like, or what is in your table after you import the csv. So I can't really comment any further I'm afraid.